# Cannot use constraint layout

Tags: android

```
C:\Users\Juan\AndroidStudioProjects\Sinergi\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_feed.xml:90: error: attribute layout_constraintStart_toStartOf (aka com.living_algorithm.sinergi:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf) not found.
C:\Users\Juan\AndroidStudioProjects\Sinergi\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_feed.xml:90: error: attribute layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf (aka com.living_algorithm.sinergi:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf) not found.
```

My error

```
Command: C:\Users\Juan\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar\54a0692c01a8c149cd9024715c187bd5\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        C:\Users\Juan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
        --manifest\
        C:\Users\Juan\AndroidStudioProjects\Sinergi\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        C:\Users\Juan\AndroidStudioProjects\Sinergi\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @C:\Users\Juan\AndroidStudioProjects\Sinergi\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        C:\Users\Juan\AndroidStudioProjects\Sinergi\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
        --custom-package\
        com.living_algorithm.sinergi\
        -0\
        apk\
        --output-text-symbols\
        C:\Users\Juan\AndroidStudioProjects\Sinergi\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

I got this error automatically while i was dragging some image and text. Can anyone help me ?

HEre is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".feed"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

my image view

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_width="329dp"
                android:layout_height="188dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.205"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView6"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/photo1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_width="51dp"
                android:layout_height="73dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/face" />
```

my Text View

```
  <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="John Wick"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView11"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView6"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

my Text View


 <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:text="German far-right mobilized by 'fake news' after stabbing: officials"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView5" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:text="Reporter"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView6"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8" />
```

next line

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:text="DRESDEN/BERLIN (Reuters) - Far-right groups spread “fake news” on social media to mobilize their supporters for violent protests targeting migrants after the fatal stabbing of a German man, said officials in the eastern German state of Saxony where they took place."
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView10" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/menu"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Anyone can help me ? I dont know why does it happen after i move my image or should i downgrade gradle plugin from 3.2.0 to 3.1.4 because i heard that it always happen in gradle plugin version 3.2.0

Comment: share your activity_feed.xml please

Comment: Do you have the dependency on constraint layout in your build.gradle? :)

Answer (score 0):

you'd need to add the mandatory attributes `app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf` and `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf` to the XML, which defines that [Constraintlayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout).

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using the `app` namespace not correctly. I guess you are referencing the `layout_constraintStart_toStartOf` like the following:

```
<SomeView app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="..." />
```

and are referencing the app namespace not correctly up in the xml file.

If the `ConstraintLayout` is your root view it has to look like the following

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" />
```

look out for the value of `xmlns:app`.

If you need to reference custom attributes of custom views in you app package you have to define a different namespace in your root view

`xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.customviews"`